# How to get rid of blue line in regression plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, regression

I have a regression plot with a blue (`lsline`) which I want to eliminate it but I don't know how.

```
plotregression(y.testTargets, y.outputs)
```

Comment: Why not just call `plot(y.testTragets, y.outputs, 'ko')` if you don't want the regression line?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the line in a regression plot if a regression plot is what you want to use?.... It's like saying you want to order a cheese hamburger with no cheese.  That isn't a cheeseburger then... so drawing from this, your regression plot without a regression line is not a regression plot... it's just **a plot**.  Just plot the actual points themselves! `plot(y.testTargets, y.outputs, 'b.');`

Comment: I want the y=x line in the plot but I don't like the blue line .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove just the blue line you can use `findall` to retrieve the handle to the line object and then `delete` it. Also based on @rayreng's feedback, I made it so that the line is automatically removed from the legend as well.

```
r = plotregression(rand(5,1), rand(5,1));

%// Make the legend dynamic before removing the line
legend('-DynamicLegend', 'Location', get(legend, 'Location'));

%// Remove the blue line (with the "Fit" label)
delete(findall(r, 'DisplayName', 'Fit'));
```

[image]

Comment: Would there be a way to remove the legend entry of the line too?... just curious.  The line gets removed, but the legend entry signifying that the line is there is still present.... as much as I think that this question doesn't make sense, this has sparked my interest now.

Comment: @rayryeng Updated.

Comment: @rayryeng If the `plotregression` command didn't put the legend over in the top left you could just call `legend('-DynamicLegend')` before removing the line.